# magento 1.9, required attribute is not selected (Alert), where to find

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

When I create a dropdown attribute mandatory choice, it creates the attribute in the product normally.
  When you do not choose an option, and try to add the product to cart, it generates an alert java script, as shown in image 1.
I need to know where, in which js file, I find this code: alert ('Please, select item');

NOTE:'ve looked in several files, but do not have much knowledge in magento to find the file.

Thank you so much
[image]

Comment: May be you need to select some option by default, or disable button?

Comment: I need to know where is this piece of code that generates this alert.

Comment: Did you try to grep?

Comment: sorry, I use windows. Neither knew this command.